# Php database information sorting

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get php to give me some statistics on my participants list. I need to know how many people of each status there are per affiliation (from)
Is there any easy way to do this if you do not know all the affiliations and stati?

```
<?php
include 'includes/config.php';

$sql="SELECT * FROM participants ORDER BY `from`, `status`";

$self = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Affiliation</th><th>Status</th></tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($self)) {
   echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['from']."</td><td>".$row['status']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

The structure of the database is 
`Name - Affiliation - Status`

So everyone who registers will be put in like
`Bob - Minnesota University - Phd Student`

Now I want a list of all the affiliations and per affiliation I need a list of all the stati and how many people share them.

So like:
`Minnesota University
Phd Student: 5
Professor: 12
Bachelor Student: 4
Caltech
Phd Student: 1
Professor: 14
Bachelor Student:32`

Comment: Could you clarify a little better what you need? Maybe provide your table structure and sample data?

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Can you post includes/config.php ?

Comment: I've added some extra info

Answer (score 0):

This may be the way:

```
$sql="SELECT count(*) as total_status, * FROM participants 
    GROUP BY `status`, `from`  ORDER BY `from`";

    $self = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Affiliation</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Total Status</th>
            </tr>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($self)) {
       echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row['name']."</td>
                <td>".$row['from']."</td>
                <td>".$row['status']."</td>
                <td>".$row['total_status']."</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. but from what I can tell it tried to find the amount of affiliations per name?

name is the name of a participant who has an affiliation to something and also has a status. So I want to list all the affiliations and see how many of each status they have.

Comment: It gives Affiliation, Staus, and count of that status for that Affiliation,

Change it to "SELECT count(*) as total_status, * FROM participants GROUP BY `status`, `from` ORDER BY `from`";